# Max value of Paramiko SSH connection timeout?

Tags: python, ssh, timeout, paramiko

In current experience the max Paramiko SSHClient timeout value is about 20 s. Is it possible some how to set it for 60 and more seconds?

This connection setting gives me timeout after 20s, even it's set to 60 s:

```
self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.ssh.connect(self.cfg.ip, port=self.cfg.port, username=self.cfg.user, password=self.cfg.password, timeout=60)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the timeout is caused by your client and not by the server?

Comment: I got this error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. But now I'm a little bit confused about this timeout thing. I need more investigation here...

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to set it at kernel level. Paramiko set the timeout via `socket.settimeout()`, and this through the OS (I'm not sure of this, but your case seems so). Linux have its timeout set to 20 seconds ([read this](http://www.sekuda.com/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout)). In that same link, they explain how to increase the socket timeout:

> I recommend that you set it to a value of 6, 7, or at most 8. 6 gives an effective connect timeout ceiling of around 45 seconds, 7 gives around 90 seconds, and 8 gives around 190 seconds.
>
> ```
>   # cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries 
>   5
>   # echo 6 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries
> ```
>
> Or use the sysctl command:
>
> ```
>   # sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries
>   net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 5
>   # sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=6
>   net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 6
> ```
>
> To make this value stick across reboots however you need to add it to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:
>
> ```
>   net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 6
> ```